# AppSettingsSection object return null reference

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I get a null reference error for the object settingsA. Please can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim configA As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.StartupPath & "xmlXirna.exe")
    Dim settingsA As AppSettingsSection = configA.AppSettings

    settingsA.Settings.Item("phrase").Value = "A quick brown fox"
    configA.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full)
    sAttrib = settingsA.Settings.Item("phrase").Value
    MsgBox(sAttrib)

End Sub
```

The corresponding App.config file is:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="phrase" value="Value of key 0 is nothing but zero"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When checking the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration?view=net-5.0#System_Configuration_ConfigurationManager_OpenExeConfiguration_System_String_  it appears that you do not include ".exe" when in debug mode.

Comment: If you use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) (or [Path.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.join?view=net-5.0) if applicable), it won't matter that `Application.StartupPath` does not/may not have a trailing directory separator character.

Comment: ... for `Application.StartupPath & "xmlXirna.exe"`.